# Comparing the Bounds of Functions

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I understand the general idea of the bounds of functions; for example, if we say a function

> *ƒ1(n) ∈ Ω(n^2)*

Then we know that *ƒ1(n)* is an element within the constraints of the lower bound *n^2*, meaning *ƒ1(n)* can be any function which grows slower or equal to that of *n^2*.

Now I start to get confused when we talk about other functions in regards to the bounds of *ƒ1(n)*. For example, say we have a statement which claims something like this:

> **If**
>
> *ƒ1(n) ∈ Ω(n^2)*
>
> **And**
>
> *ƒ2(n) ∈ Θ(n)*
>
> **Then**
>
> *ƒ2(n) ∈ O(ƒ1(n))*

I have a hard time telling whether or not it's true or false. I have two different approaches which contradict each other:

- ***true*** - Since *ƒ2* is tightly bound under *n*, it can be considered an element within the constraints of *O(ƒ1(n))* because *ƒ2* does not grow slower than *ƒ1*.
- ***false*** - Since *ƒ1* has a lower bound of *n^2*, the function *ƒ2*, which is tightly bound under *n*, cannot be considered an element of the upper bounds of *ƒ1* since we know *ƒ1* will not have an upper bound which grows slower than *n^2*.

Both of these approaches I've thought of seem valid to me; I think I'm getting confused on whether or not we care about the lower bounds of *ƒ1* when we're trying to decide if another function is an element of its upper bounds.

Any help on clarifying this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this question should rather be asked on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rolve I've seen algorithm questions asked on here and cs exchange so I was unsure where to post it - is there a way to move this question over there or should I close / repost on cs exchange?

Comment: When I voted to close the question, it suggested me places to migrate this question to, but CS was not in the list. So maybe you have to repost, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @rolve Okay, I think I'll leave it here a little while longer and see what other people think (whether I should move this to the cs exchange or if it's okay here etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the definitions of big-O etc. All formulas are valid for sufficiently large n. Then, there exist some constants `k`, such that:

First formula:

> ƒ1(n) ∈ Ω(n^2) 
>   ⇔ k1 * n^2 <= f1(n)

Second formula:

> ƒ2(n) ∈ Θ(n) 
>   ⇔ k2 * n <= f2(n) <= k3 * n

We know that `k3 * n < k1 * n^2` (again, for sufficiently large `n`). Hence:

> k2 * n <= f2(n) <= k3 * n < k1 * n^2 <= f1(n)

This can be reduced to

> f2(n) < f1(n)

With this knowledge, we see that the inferred formula is true:

> ƒ2(n) ∈ O(ƒ1(n)) 
>   ⇔ f2(n) <= k4 * f1(n)

Comment: So does the fact that ƒ1(n) has a lower bound not affect ƒ2(n) when talking about whether not not ƒ2(n) ∈ O(ƒ1(n))?

Comment: No, that's a necessary condition. The fact that `f1(n)` is lower-bounded by `n^2` lets use do the immediate step (`k3 * n < k1 * n^2`). If `f1(n)` wasn't bounded, we could not do this step and could not say anything about whether ƒ2(n) ∈ O(ƒ1(n))  or not.

Comment: I understand this much better now with your mathematical approach; thank you I really appreciate it.